# Infinite composition of functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If we define a function $f(x)=-x$ and try and find $f^\infty(x)$ whare $f^n(x)$ is $f$ composed with itself $n$ can we say
$$x=f^\infty(c)$$
$$f^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(f^\infty(c))$$
$$-x=f^\infty(c)$$
$$-x=x$$
$$x=0$$
and then say that $\underbrace{---...-}_\text{infinite times}3=0$ or is thare a flaw in this logic?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle thing going on here. $f^{\inf}$ as you define it is badly defined but for $x = 0$ in the sense that the limit $lim_{n->\inf} f^{n}(x)$ does not converge unless x = 0.

Thus saying that if we multiply $-3$ infinite times by $-1$ its equal to 0 is wrong: the subsecuence $f^{2n}(3)$ is equal to 3 as n goes to infinity, and $f^{2n+1}(3)$ goes to $-3$, but the limit of $f^{n}(3)$ is not defined.